# CSS Line-height, I should need 100% (little banner construction)

Tags: html, css

I want to get the following:

```
                  BANNER IMAGE
                  BANNER IMAGE
Menu left         BANNER IMAGE             Menu right
```

it used to be easy to reach with tables.

```
<div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 20%;">menu left</div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 60%;">picture</div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 20%;">menu right</div>
</div>
```

the picture in the middle sets the actual height. I was trying to use the line-height property, when I give px, it works OK, but this time I need 100%. Setting the height: 100% wont let me align the text middle, bottom etc. Anyway, should I need those widths? Can anybody help?

Comment: all :) (dummyCharactersSoThatThisTextboxAcceptIt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jjqS5/1/

Do you want something like that?

Comment: would have been better if the banner image would set the height. And left, right menu are fixed heights, if it gets longer, it ruins the design

Comment: The banner image sets the height, if you remove the height value in #banner. What content will the menus contain? Is the height predictable or not?